# WCF service is not exposing methods when called from windows PHONE 8.1

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8.1

As I am using Windows phone 8.1 I am not able to call my WCF service the way I have for previous applications.

After some searching I was able to find the below alternative to call a service from window phone 8.1

```
try
{
    string responseBodyAsText;

    HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:50436/FabSvc.svc");
    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string status = res.StatusCode + " " + res.ReasonPhrase + Environment.NewLine;
    responseBodyAsText = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    responseBodyAsText = responseBodyAsText.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine); // Insert new lines
    string output = responseBodyAsText;
}
catch (HttpRequestException hre)
{
    string status = hre.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // For debugging
    string status = ex.ToString();
}
```

This code returns a status code of OK (see below) along with some basic data. But my problem is that I can't work out how access any of the methods from this point. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

EDIT: Current WCF Service (Simplified)

`service.svc`

```
namespace ServiceName.WCF
{
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class FabSvc : ICollection, ICompositionType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Pings this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Ping()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all CompositionTypes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<CompositionTypeBase> GetAllCompositionTypes()
    {
        List<CompositionTypeBase> allCompositionTypes = new List<CompositionTypeBase>();
        try
        {
            allCompositionTypes = CompositionTypeBase.GetAllCompositionTypes();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return allCompositionTypes;
    }
}
```

`Icollection.cs`

```
namespace ServiceName.WCF
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface ICollection
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<CollectionBase> GetAllCollections();
    }
}
```

`CollectionBase.cs`

```
namespace ServiceName.WCF.Entities
{
    public class CollectionBase
    {
        public int CollectionID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all seasons.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<CollectionBase> GetAllCollections()
        {
            List<CollectionBase> allCollections = new List<CollectionBase>();
            IEnumerable<Collection> collections = Collection.GetAll();
            foreach (var collection in collections)
            {
                CollectionBase seasonBase = new CollectionBase();
                seasonBase.CollectionID = collection.CollectionID;
                seasonBase.Description = collection.Description;
                allCollections.Add(seasonBase);
            }
            return allCollections;
        }
    }
}
```

`Web.config`

```
        <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
        <add key="ImageFilePath" value="C:\websites\images\"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="20000000" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="50" />
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" openTimeout="12:00:00" receiveTimeout="12:00:00" sendTimeout="12:00:00" closeTimeout="12:00:00">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
      </system.webServer>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ServiceNameEntities" connectionString="CONNECTION_STRING_INFO" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post how your service looks ? You will have to generate the proxy of your WCF service and include it in the code that is pushed to the windows phone to use the methods using the proxyclient class rather than using httpClient

Comment: @Rajesh I have added the WCF code as requested, but did not know what was required and what should be omitted. In the interests of making this question more readable for future readers could you please let me know what can be removed

Comment: Looking at your service you will have to create a client proxy of the service using svcutil and wsdl. Once the clientproxy is generated include this in your app to perform the method calls to your WCF service. This should be very similar to any .NET client that wishes to communicate with your WCF Service

Answer (score 0):

When you use HttpClient, you intend to post data to an endpoint, so there's no contracts here.

You "see" the operations when you create a proxy, by addind a reference or using wcfutil.

For a RestFul service, you could simply call the operation like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:50436/FabSvc.svc/GetAllCollections/value");
```

But your service is expecting a SOAP request, so you need to make a request with a SOAP/XML in order to consume your method.
Inside the SOAP envelope you inform the service the operation you want to hit, like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <OperationName xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

You can also include the operation in the Header.
In the exemple below, I used WebClient:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = GetSoap();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
    client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/ICollection/GetAllCollections\"");
    var response = client.UploadString("http://localhost:50436/FabSvc.svc", data);
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

Hope it helps